# Why does this show as a syntax error on Verilog?

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

I'm a newbie to Verilog, and I'm trying to follow the few youtube videos I've seen that use vscode as text editor for Verilog.
However, I get an error in the Verilog file itself. Here's my code:

```
module test(A, B, C)
    
    input A; 
    output B;
    output C;
    assign B = A;
    assign C = !A;
endmodule
```

And here's the error I get, with line 3 being the `input A;` line:

```
./test.v:3: syntax error
I give up.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy to get a helpful error message with any simulator in this case.  The `module` line needs to end with a semicolon.
Change:

```
module test(A, B, C)
```

to:

```
module test(A, B, C);
```

---

Unrelated to your error, here is the recommended way to declare module ports.  It uses the ANSI-style, which simplifies the code and avoids common Verilog errors associated with having duplicate port lists:

```
module test (
    input  A,
    output B,
    output C
);
    assign B = A;
    assign C = !A;
endmodule
```